# Installing Windows on Macbook(5,1) should I use 32 or 64 bit?

Tags: windows-7, macos, boot-camp

This [page](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1846) says my Macbook version (5,1 released end of '08) doesn't support Windows 64bit but "can use" it.  This is pretty vague, am I going to run into issues down the road if I install the 64bit version?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally have mid 2009 13" MBP. I have windows 7 x64 Professional installed, and it works great.

Whether Apple officially supports something does not have much association with whether it will work great or not.

Answer (score 1):

MacBook "Core 2 Duo" 2.0 13" (Unibody)  2.0 GHz Core 2 Duo (P7350)
Intro Date:     October 14, 2008    Disc Date:  June 8, 2009

I own the above Macbook and let me share my experience.

1. I have install OSX 10.7, and capable to upgrade to 10.8.
2. I can install Windows 7 64-bit through Boot camp, but driver including screen brightness control short-cut key, etc,  was not function
3. I have 8GB RAM installed, and recognized by Windows 7 64 Bit and OSX.

Comment: Do you have something other than personal experience to back this up?

Comment: My experience has gone pretty well, a few minor issues such as display and keyboard lighting not turning off when dimming them all the way down to the minimal level.